# Unclear on an algebra step in Laurent series of cotangent.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm reading through a calculation for $\displaystyle z\pi\cot(\pi z)=\pi iz+\frac{2\pi iz}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}$ which confuses me. It states
$$
\begin{align*}
z\pi\cot(\pi z) 
&= \pi iz+\frac{2\pi iz}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi iz)^k}{k!}}\\
&= \pi iz+\frac{1}{1-(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi iz)^k}{(k+1)!})}\\
&=\pi iz+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi iz)^k}{(k+1)!}\right)^n\\
&=\pi iz+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}(2\pi iz)^k
\end{align*}
$$
where $B_k$ is the $k$th Bernoulli number. I don't follow the last equality from the third to fourth line. How does it follow? Thanks.

Comment: Equation (4) looks like it's immediate from (1), while (2) and (3) don't seem to serve any purpose to me. *Remark*. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)'s the generating function for the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Oh, that makes it much easier to see. Thanks!